# Add mapView to JPanel in java

Tags: java, jxmapviewer, jxmaps

I want to add a map view in a JPanel, i am using jxMaps from teamdev. I try this code, but i doesn't work.

```
    Map sample = new Map();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Map");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panelMap = new JPanel();
    panelMap.setLayout(null);
    panelMap.add(sample, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelMap.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
    panelMap.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panelMap);
```

I hope you can help me!

Here the class Map

```
    public class Map extends MapView {
    public Map() {

    setOnMapReadyHandler(new MapReadyHandler() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapStatus status) {
            if (status == MapStatus.MAP_STATUS_OK) {
                final Map map = getMap();
                MapOptions options = new MapOptions(map);
                MapTypeControlOptions controlOptions = new MapTypeControlOptions(map);
                controlOptions.setPosition(ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
                options.setMapTypeControlOptions(controlOptions);
                map.setOptions(options);
                map.setCenter(new LatLng(map, 35.91466, 10.312499));

                map.setZoom(2.0);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This example is from jxMap ,https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps

Comment: Which `Map` is imported?

Comment: There is the code @UsagiMiyamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is layout error. If you set **null** layout for container you have to set bounds for each child component manually. Your code sample didn't have any calls that set bounds for Map instance. In other words, after:

```
panelMap.setLayout(null);
```

you have to set bounds for Map instance:

```
sample.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
```